# Run tests in parallel using the Visual Studio Test task is failing

Tags: azure-devops

We are trying to Run tests in parallel using the Visual Studio Test task based on below link but we noticed "Run Unit tests" step failing due to packages directory was not found. Trying to contact Azure DevOps team to get some help here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-vstest?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hi @NAGAJU and welcome to stackoverflow.com :). It would help if you could phrase your question as a question and also if you could include details about how you defined the VS Test task and also include the relevant log messages. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried to publish the test files as artifacts from the first job. And download the test artifacts to the second job. But we found the test files were located separately and there were many test data files needed to be published too. It was hard to publish all the test files to azure devops sever. And the vstest task failed with either assemblies not found error or some testcases just failed.

We also tried configuring a single job running in parallel with both build tasks and vstest task. It turned out the publish build artifacts task didnot work properly in parallel jobs.

After many times try and working together with @NAGAJU. The workaround we found is to configure two agent jobs to separate the publish artifacts task and Vstest task.

The first agent job with build tasks and publish artifacts tasks runs in an single agent. The second job with build tasks and Vstest task to run the tests in multiple agents in parallel.

Comment: Thanks Levi for quick response. I have tried the options you mentioned but it is still failing with different error. I am copying my build pipeline Link here.Can you please help me check what was wrong in these steps?
https://twcdot.visualstudio.com/Data/_apps/hub/ms.vss-ciworkflow.build-ci-hub?_a=edit-build-definition&id=225