# System BadImageFormatException Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, xunit.net, vstest, microsoft-extensions-logging

CI pipeline taking about 50 min to complete and most of the time is consumed by the test. Have good number of unit test and data driven tests. Have decided to run test in parallel and the approach took based on this doc 
[Run Tests In Parallel In Build Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-vstest?view=azure-devops#run-tests-in-parallel-in-build-pipelines)

Idea is to split pipeline into 3 jobs

1. **Build Job** : builds the binaries and publish them to artifacts with
   name pre-drop.
2. **Test Job**: downloads the artifact pre-drop, extract files, run tests parallel using VSTest@2 task
3. **Publish Job**: publish the artifacts to drop(for release pipeline).

Not sure if I was able to get my idea into .yml.

Test Job

```
- job : 'TestJob'
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  strategy:
    parallel: 2
  dependsOn: 'BuildJob'

  steps:

  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    inputs:
      buildType: 'current'
      downloadType: 'single'
      artifactName: 'predrop'
      downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

  - task: ExtractFiles@1
    inputs:
      archiveFilePatterns: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/predrop/predrop.zip'
      destinationFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/predrop/Extpredrop'

  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: |
       **\*tests.dll
       !**\*TestAdapter.dll
       !**\obj\**
      searchFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
      vstestLocationMethod: 'location'
      vstestLocation: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\'
      otherConsoleOptions: '/platform:x64 /Framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'
```

The issue is with VSTest task recognizing & running some tests but erroring out on other tests with following error on some of the tests

```
System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. 
Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.
```

The binaries from the first job has generated Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll as part of the artifact.

Comment: All seems good so it could be one single piece in configuration. It would be handy if you share with us your YAML file.

Comment: wild guess: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/415 relelated ?

Comment: updated yaml for test job

Answer (score 2):

The document of [BadImageFormatException Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=netframework-4.8) says this exception is thrown in below scenario:

- A DLL or executable is loaded as a 64-bit assembly, but it contains 32-bit features or resources. For example, it relies on COM interop or calls methods in a 32-bit dynamic link library.
- To address this exception, set the project's Platform target property to x86 (instead of x64 or AnyCPU) and recompile.

So you can try configuring the VSBuild task to rebuild the project as x86 or x64.  Check out this similar error in [this thread](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t8223-).

If above changing the platform doesnot work. You can try this workaround to add a VSBuild task to build your project in job **TestJob** too. In this way, there will be no need to **download** and **extract** the artifacts in job **TestJob**. For below example:

```
- job : 'TestJob'
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  strategy:
    parallel: 2
  dependsOn: 'BuildJob'

  steps:
  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      platform: "any cpu"
      configuration: 'Release'

  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      ...
```

You can also check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165181/run-tests-in-parallel-using-the-visual-studio-test-task-is-failing/61182692#61182692).